# How do I use csv_writer to write a list into separate rows?

Tags: python, csv

I used [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract a html table and store elements in a list. Next, I would like to write the list into a .csv file, but it looks like the writerow function doesn't write elements into different rows.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Grab first table (station table in html file)
def parse_station(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    s_table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
    stations = []
    for tr in s_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        td = tr.find_all('td')[1]
        td = td.get_text()
        stations.append(td)

    return stations


stations = parse_station(open('data.html').read())

with open('stations.csv', "wb") as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow([stations])
f.close()
```

The .csv is like:

```
A,B,C,D,E
```

instead of:

```
A,
B,
C,
D,
E,
```

What's wrong with my code? How can I fix it? (I'm using Python 2.7)

Comment: could you print `stations` and post it here? just how it looks like

Comment: CSV format is usually comma/tab separated on ONE row line so if each letter would be in its own line, there would be no comma.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this sample code

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['A'])
    writer.writerow(['B'])
```

this will give you result like this

```
A
B
```

you can pass your value

Note: check type of stations if this will return str than your value will be in single row but if this is list that loop over list sample code for writing list into CSV.

```
>>> list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
...     writer = csv.writer(f)
...     for i in list:
...         writer.writerow([i])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pandas for get table from html with [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) and save it to csv file with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and `sep='\n'` in your case:

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = pd.read_html(your_html)
df = df_list[0]
df.to_csv('Your file', sep='\n')
```